# How to replace with zero after full-stop if not have any value using regexp_substr in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Values are like:

Num(column)

786.56

35

```
select num,regexp_substr(num,'[^.]*') "first",regexp_substr(num,'[^.]+$') "second" from cost
```

when i execute the above query output will be like

```
num       first    second  
786.56    786      56
35        35       35
```

I want to print zero if not have any value after full-stop,by default second column repeating first value

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here; using either the *occurrence* or *subexpression* parameters available in [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303).

### Subexpression - the 5<sup>th</sup> parameter

Using subexpressions you can pick out which group `()` in your match you want to return in any given function call

```
SQL> with the_data (n) as (
  2  select 786.56 from dual union all
  3  select 35 from dual
  4         )
  5  select regexp_substr(n, '^(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$', 1, 1, null, 1) as f
  6       , regexp_substr(n, '^(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$', 1, 1, null, 2) as s
  7    from the_data;

F   S
--- ---
786 56
35
```

`^(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$` means at the start of the string `^`, pick a group `()` of digits `\d+` followed by an optional `\.?`. Then, pick an optional group of digits at the end of the string `$`.

We then use sub-expressions to pick out which group of digits you want to return.

### Occurrence - the 3<sup>th</sup> parameter

If you place the number in a group and forget about matching the start and end of the string you can pick the first group of numbers and the second group of numbers:

```
SQL> with the_data (n) as (
  2  select 786.56 from dual union all
  3  select 35 from dual
  4         )
  5  select regexp_substr(n, '(\d+)\.?', 1, 1, null, 1) as f
  6       , regexp_substr(n, '(\d+)\.?', 1, 2, null, 1) as s
  7    from the_data;

F   S
--- ---
786 56
35
```

`(\d+)\.?` means pick a group `()` of digits `\d+` followed by an optional `.`. For the first group the first occurrence is the data before the `.`, for the second group the second occurrence is the data after `.`. You'll note that you still have to use the 5<sup>th</sup> parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` - subexpression - to state that you want the only the data in the group.

### Both options

You'll note that neither of these return 0 when there are no decimal places; you'll have to add that in with a [`COALESCE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm) when the return value is NULL. You also need an [explicit cast](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions024.htm#SQLRF00613) to an integer as `COALESCE()` expects consistent data types ([this is best practice anyway](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214)):

```
SQL> with the_data (n) as (
  2  select 786.56 from dual union all
  3  select 35 from dual
  4         )
  5  select cast(regexp_substr(n, '^(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$', 1, 1, null, 1) as integer) as f
  6       , coalesce(cast(regexp_substr(n, '^(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$', 1, 1, null, 2) as integer), 0) as s
  7    from the_data;

   F    S
---- ----
 786   56
  35    0
```